# Getting user name through AD using powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've been banging my head against this for a while and can't figure out why this isn't working.

```html
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Users = Get-ADGroupMember -identity “Accounting” -recursive | select name | export-csv -path "D:\group.csv"
$csv = Import-Csv "D:\group.csv"
foreach ($user in $csv) {Get-ADUser -filter "'Name -eq  ""$user""'"}
```

Comment: You received error messages. You should include those in your post to help people trying to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of issues here I think.

1. You export the data just to import it again. Do you even need a second copy of the data?
2. `Import-Csv` will return an object array not just the names. There is more than one way to address this but this should be more what you are looking for

---

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Users = Get-ADGroupMember -identity “Accounting” -recursive | select name
foreach ($user in $Users) {Get-ADUser -filter {Name -eq $user.Name}}
```

Even that is more than it needs to be. Its redundant since `Get-ADGroupMember` already returns similar objects you need. What do you need to do with this data? If you really need `Get-AdUser` then just pipe the output to it.

```
Get-ADGroupMember -identity “Accounting” -recursive | Get-Aduser
```

Comment: As far as curly braces for filtering is concerned, the `-Filter` parameter actually expects a string, so using quotes is a more consistent way of getting filters to work.

Answer (score 0):

`$user` is a row in the CSV file. You need to address the `Name` field of that row (you also have way too many single- and double-quotes).

```
foreach ($user in $csv) {Get-ADUser -filter "Name -eq  '$($user.name)'"}
```

Or you could make the CSV file just a vanilla listing of names, and not read it as CSV:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -identity “Accounting” -recursive | select -expandproperty name | out-file "c:\group.txt"

$csv = get-content -path "c:\group.txt"
foreach ($user in $csv) {Get-ADUser -filter "Name -eq  '$user'"}
```

But if you're only using the file as a conduit between the group search and the user lookup, you can skip that entirely by piping the output of `Get-ADGroupMember` directly to `Get-ADUser`.

```
Get-ADGroupMember -identity “Accounting” -recursive | Get-ADUser;
```

Comment: Yes. The *outer* double-quotes trigger the variable expansion, and the filter accepts the string enclosed in single quotes. Run it & see for yourself. The `Filter` becomes `Name -eq 'myusernamehere'`